# Notepad ++ to count the number of occurrences of a string per line, to be used to pad a sql import file

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a file with variable columns that I'm converting to a SQL import file, or csv is you will.

The file is setup as follows:

```
    Account     Source    Source2    Source3    Source4    Source5              
'39','39'
'41','41'
'67','67'
'286','286'
'299','299','2312210299'
'307','307'
'341','341'
'349','349'
'351','351'
'359','359'
'362','362'
'363','363'
'378','378'
'511','511','6218','2197360511'
```

I'm trying to use **Regex** to find the number of occurrences of each string per line so I can pad with `NULL`, but just can't seem to get it right.

If I search for `'[0-9]\*'`, it finds each instance.

If I search for `['[0-9]\*']\*$`, it will find the last instance in each line.

If I use `'[0-9]\*'{2}$`, it doesn't find any with 2 occurrences per line, and from what I'm finding online, that should be the syntax.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: What exactly would you like to extract and/or match?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What do you expect?

Comment: I don't really understand what is so baffling about or unclear about the question? he has 6 columns and has varying amount of values on each row, so of course he needs to pad each row with a varying amount of commas so that each row has data for six columns (with the missing ones having null value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's get the reasoning behind why the things you tried didn't work first.

> If I search for `'[0-9]*'`, it finds each instance

Yes that's exactly what it is supposed to do; I'm sure you already figured that out.

> If I search for `['[0-9]*']*$`, it will find the last instance in each line

I'm not sure where you're going with this one, square bracketts within square bracketts is a terrible idea.

> If I search for `['[0-9]*']*$`, it will find the last instance in each line. If I use `'[0-9]*'{2}$`, it doesn't find any with 2 occurrences per line, and from what I'm finding online, that should be the syntax

See the reason this didn't work is because `'[0-9]*'{2}$` will match 2 multidigit numbers (or no digits at all because you're using asterisk) back to back. But the numbers in your dataset are separated by a  `,` you **HAVE** to take that into account. Regex is an explicit tool.

What you'd do instead is this - `^('[0-9]*',?){2}$`

Notice the presence, of an optional `,` in the capture group. The above regex will match lines with 2 numbers within quotes (or no numbers at all but just a `''` since we're using asterisk) separated by a `,`.

Here's the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/1S9Bqu/1)

I'm not exactly sure whether this was what you wanted, if not, just comment it down and I'll edit the answer to provide more stuff.

Comment: Thanks Chase, I was trying to figure out how to incorporate the comma into my search, but then the last instance of my data doesn't have the comma, and, well, I'm new to regex, and haven't quite wrapped my head around the whole thing.